# How to control Zarya's Graviton Surge position?

Tags: overwatch

I believe there is a way to control Zarya's Graviton Surge position, what is it?   I mean, you can clearly aim it and set direction, but **how to set flight distance at which it will be triggered?**

All guides, which I've found completely ignore this question and talk about pulling range and when to use the ability only, not about How to use it.

Comment: I believe the best approach would be to go to the practice range with her and practice aiming the graviton projectile. You could also set up a custom game with increased Ultimate Charge Rate.

Comment: @Wikwocket, before doing it you need to know that this is a projectile ;) Also, even when you know an experiment can only discard a hypothesis, not confirm it, you never can be sure this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graviton Surge starts as a small, arching projectile, similar to her alternate fire, and will expand into the surge itself as soon as it hits a solid surface.

It cannot activate in mid air, you have to fire it into a floor or wall in order to trigger to ult itself.

Comment: Does it trigger, when you hit an enemy with it?